# How to prevent HTML forms being sent multiple times in a row within a short time period?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this simple form to implement a login:

```
<form action="/handleLogin/" name="login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="userid">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="userid" name="identifier" value="" pattern="\s*([^@\s]+@[^@\s]+|\d+)\s*" data-parsley-required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="userpassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="userpassword" name="credential" data-parsley-required>
    </div>
    <button id="login-button" class="button" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Our QA team noticed that it's possible to click the login-button twice or hammer the return button on the keyboard two times in a row within a short period of time.

This leads to multiple requests being sent to the server which causes problems.

Thus, I tried to prevent this with the following JavaScript code:

```
$('form[name="login"]').on('submit', function() {
    $("#userid, #userpassword, #login-button").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Unfortunately, now the values of username + password won't be sent to the server anymore. I guess that's because they're disabled and the browsers thinks: "Ok, if the fields are disabled, I'm not gonna send em".

How can I work around this problem?

I thought about canceling the original submit event using "return false;" and manually send a copy of the form but that's not really a very good solution, I think.

Comment: disable only `#login-button`

Comment: why are you trying to fix your server side problems on the client side?

Comment: @Paweł What if the user has his cursor within the login or pwd input field and then hits return on the keyboard twice?

Comment: You should implement some redirect with your action if the login is successful.

Comment: @madalinivascu Because the server-side fix seems to be very complicated and we thought maybe we can implement an easy fix on the frontend.

Comment: set a var vor lastSendTime before the onsubmit function, in the function ``event.preventDefault(); if(timeNow < (lastSendTime + timeout)) {return} else {lastSendTime = timeNow; submit();}``  <-- just the logic. i think you can write the code by yourself

Comment: @Timo how hard can it be to add a if in there to test if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: It should be enough adding a redirect on top of page login and loginHandler whenever the user is already logged in

Comment: @madalinivascu i.e. a selenium bot tries to login several times with different key value pairs to bruteforce your page the server will get flooded with mass of requests. build in a timer that allows only all 10seconds to use the action and you minify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('form[name="login"]').on('submit', function() {
   $("#login-button").attr("disabled", true);
   $("#userid, #userpassword").attr("readonly", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$('button[type=submit], input[type=submit]').prop('disabled',true);`

instead of:

`$("#userid, #userpassword, #login-button").attr("disabled", true);`

It will only disable button.

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/s3kbvLe1/)